# Is the matrix transpose of a stabilizer also a stabilizer?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, and $v\in R^2$ a vector. Let $G := \text{Stab}_{\text{GL}_2(R)}(v)$. Is $G^T$ (the group of transposes of matrices in $G$) the stabilizer of something? (Here, in both cases $GL_2(R)$ is acting on 'column vectors' by "left multiplication")

Ie, is there a vector $w\in R^2$ such that $G^T = \text{Stab}_{\text{GL}_2(R)}(w)$?

Comment: @MorganRodgers You say it doesn't have a meaningful interpretation in this context, but I don't see any context in the question. I think it can be given an interpretation: it's the dual rep of $G$ (essentially). Even without the interpretation I would have considered the question algebraically interesting on its own (at least if it didn't have a trivial answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For instance consider $R=\mathbb{R}$ and $v=[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}]$.